# Netbeans: SASS compilation problems

Tags: netbeans, sass

Hello with a fresh installation of Netbeans I get the following error message when saving a .scss file:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Scout\vendor\gems\bin\sass.bat" "--cache-location" "C:\Users\********\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.0.2\sass-compiler" "--debug-info" "C:\xampp\htdocs\sasstest\scss\test.scss" "C:\xampp\htdocs\sasstest\css\test.css"
Der Befehl ""jruby-complete.jar"" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.
Done.
```

- ruby 1.9.3p327 is installed and works
- if Scout is configured and started everything works just nice
- SASS path is set to: C:\Program Files (x86)\Scout\vendor\gems\bin\sass.bat
- Input/Output paths are set correctly
- also I installed jRuby but it did not fix the problem

Translation of the error message: The command ""jruby-complete.jar"" is spelled incorrectly or cannot be found.

Any idea how I could get the compilation of SCSS files in Netbeans (8.0.2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.

- Added jruby-complete.jar to path (maybe not necessary)
- followed these instructions: http://xuad.net/artikel/sass-scss-unter-netbeans-verwenden.html

Found out that sass.bat in from the Scout installation is different from sass.bat in the ruby installation folder, specifying "C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\sass.bat" in the Netbeans settings worked.